# CSS3 2D Transform Module: multiple functions: order of function application in noncommutative case

Tags: css, matrix, transform, transformation

In the section 2-dimensional transforms the book "*CSS Animations and Transitions for the Modern Web*" by *Adobe press* states:

> You can nest transforms as many levels deep as you want. The result
>   applies the first transformation, then applies the second
>   transformation, then the third, and so on.

What I wanted to know, which is not clear from the book, is whether the functions
in the function list are composed (i.e. applied to the object to be transformed)
in a left-to-right or right-to-left fashion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions in the function list are applied right-to-left.

This can be seen by looking at the browser output for the following code snippet I put together:

I wanted to investigate whether the listed functions are composed right-to-left or left-to-right,
so I tested things out with the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example Code</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Example Code" />
    <meta name="author" content="John Doe" />
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
}
        #container {
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: purple;
        }
        .box {
            padding: 50px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-clip: content-box;
            background-color: yellow;
            transform-origin: 50px 50px;
        }
        .box.one:hover {
            transform: translateX(100px) skewY(30deg);
        }
        .box.two:hover {
            transform: skewY(30deg) translateX(100px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box one">
            HELLO
        </div>
        <div class="box two">
            WORLD
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In these case the translateX and skewY transformations do not commute (i.e. order matters).
What I found, and this information seems to be lacking in the book, is that to derive the
transformed picture, you first need to apply the transformation on the right (e.g. skewY
for box one) and then apply each transformation to its left in turn (e.g. translateX
for box one). In each case the operation is computed with respect to the origin which
I have set to be the upper left hand corner of the yellow rectangle.

What I found about the order of application of transformations in the transformation list
is consistent with what I found on the CSS3 spec (and with other computer graphics systems
such as OpenGL/WebGL):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#propdef-transform

> The final transformation value for a coordinate system is obtained by
>   converting each function in the list to its corresponding matrix like
>   defined in Mathematical Description of Transform Functions, then
>   multiplying the matrices.